# Can he/she get admission for Phd in U.S/European university?

Tags: phd

If someone have done Post -Graduation from not reputed institution (India) and have   not done  any project /Thesis in Msc  and Msc percentage/mark also low  ?

Can he/she get admission  for Phd  in U.S/European university ?

Notes : Department  is Mathematics

Comment: Is your question actually whether one "can" get an admission (i.e., is it possible) or whether it's likely? It's certainly possible by regulation, but if there is no real redeeming qualities in your CV getting accepted is unlikely.

Comment: thanks for correction@xLeitix  im   not getting  its  certainly possible  by  regulation  can u elaborate more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible to say with only the information given. It would probably be difficult, however, but more for low marks that the other facts.

The candidate needs to show, in application materials, a high probability of success. Nothing you state makes that success obvious. But letters of recommendation are also important and there can be reasons for low grades that aren't so much related to ability in mathematics. Even extreme focus on a research topic could cause poor performance elsewhere.

A committee would need to consider the entire package. The competition is also fierce and many in the pool won't have the same negative aspects.

It might be marginally easier to do this in the US than in EU as the doctoral education process can be longer and have more room to make up deficits.

But it isn't promising as stated.

Comment: thanks u @Buffy one more doubts  :    if some  one  have good  score in GRE   but  not have  project/thesis  during Msc.......Can  he/she  eligible  for  Phd in US

Comment: Lots of MS programs in the US don't involve a thesis, so that is less of an issue. The GRE will help, if only a bit. The subject test in mathematics is more important than the basic test, of course.